# Relation of Brownian motion and heat kernel

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, heat-equation, semigroup-of-operators

In my PDE course we had a short section on Brownian motion. Let $G_t(x):= (4\pi t)^{-\frac{n}{2}} e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4t}}$ denote the heat kernel. Then $P(t,x,y):=G_t(x-y)$ is an example for a Brownian motion. For $f\in BUC(\mathbb{R}^n)$ we have that $(T(t)f)(x):= \int P(t,x,y) f(y)\,\mathrm{dy}$ defines a $C_0$ semigroup on $BUC(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Then we have a theorem saying that the semigroup (defined as above) of a Brownian motion has generator $c\cdot \triangle$ for some $c > 0$. Then it is stated that this means $P(t,x,y) = G_{ct}(x-y)$.

The last statement is unclear to me. My idea was: Convolution with $G_{ct}(x)$ yields a solution operator for $u_t - c\triangle u = 0$. The solution operator gives raise to a semigroup with generator $c\triangle$ which is the same as for the Brownian motion semigroup above. If the fact that the generators of the semigroups agree would imply that the semigroups are the same, then the fundamental lemma would yield $P(t,x,y) = G_{ct}(x-y)$ but I don't think that this is true, since the generator is some kind of derivative of the semigroup and in most cases derivation is not an injective process.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you are asking. You write that the generator of the semigroup $T_t$ has the generator $c \Delta$ (I agree with that) and then that this means that $P(t,x,y) = G_{ct}(x-y)$.. but isn't this true by the very definition of the semigroup? You defined the semigroup via $G_t$....

Comment: One semigroup comes from $P(t,x,y)$ and one from $G_{ct}(x-y)$. We know that both semigroups have the same generator. Then my question is: Does this mean that the semigroups are the same and hence by the fundamental lemma would hold $P(t,x,y)=G_{ct}(x-y)$ almost everywhere.

Comment: Let me see whether I understand you correctly. Let $T(t)f = \int P(t,\cdot,y,) f(y) \, dy$ be a $C_0$ semigroup with generator $c \Delta$. Your question is whether this implies that $P(t,x,y) = G_{ct}(x-y)$... am I right?

Comment: Yes, this is my question.

Comment: I found out, that it is indeed true that when the generators are the same, although the semigroups are the same, theorem 3 in http://texas.math.ttu.edu/~gilliam/f06/m5340_f06/semigroups.pdf. This solves my question.

Comment: Yes, this is true, but you have to be careful about the domains. You assume that the generators are equal when restricted to the twice differentiable functions ... this is (in general) different from assuming that both generators are the same (in the sense that they have the same domain and coincide on this domain). For example if $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a $3$-dimensional Brownian motion, then there exists a function $f$ in the domain of the generator of $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ which is **not** twice differentiable.